# Console Application Output to .csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to make a program that will show the numbers:

```
    1, 10   +30
    2, 40     (the scale goes up in this pattern by adding 20 to the last number added)
    3, 90   +50
    4, 160
    5, 250  +70
```

So far I have this code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO;

 namespace Myloop
 {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              FileStream filestream = new FileStream("loopdata.csv", FileMode.Create);
              var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
              streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
              Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
              Console.SetError(streamwriter);

               int forloop;
               for (forloop = 1; forloop < 21; forloop++)
                    Console.WriteLine(forloop);

               Console.ReadLine();

          }
      }
 }
```

This is showing the first sequence of numbers 1 - 20, but could anyone give me any guidance how to do the other sequence next to it in the console application? And how I can output these to a .csv file, since the information I have so far doesn't appear in the .csv file.

Comment: in C# you can inline the int forLoop declaration into the for loop (guessing you come from C). Helps to make cleaner code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the numbers you will find that the difference between two numbers can be calculated by using the following formula:

```
valueInSecondColumn = 20 * (valueInFirstColumn + 1) - 10;
```

Applying that knowledge you can formulate a code like the following one:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
int calculatedValue = 10;

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    data.Add(string.Format("{0}, {1}", i, calculatedValue));
    calculatedValue += 20 * (i + 1) - 10;
}

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"data.txt", data.ToArray());
```

Comment: I just saw that using `valueInSecondColumn  = Math.Pow(valueInFirstColumn , 2) * 10;` as formula would of course be much easier ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Stream the console output to file first

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("loopdata.csv", FileMode.Create);
var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
Console.SetError(streamwriter);
```

Comment: Author added above code to his question and I've got -2 :( Life ;P

Answer (score 0):

One rather ugly implementation which is totally untested...

```
int col3 = 30;
bool col3set = true;

for( int col1 = 1; col1 <=20; col1++ )
{
    int col2 = col1*col1*10;

    Console.WriteLine(col1 + "," + col2 + " +" + (col3set ? col3.ToString() : ""));

    col3set = !col3set; //flip setting col3 so it's on for every odd row
    col3 += 20;
}
```

Comment: You need to add `ToString()` in 5th line. I think he add all `+ sth` as comments only because it should be proper CSV file

Comment: Hello I get an error saying conditional expression cannot be determined and this is for                                                      (col3 ) : "" );

Comment: The ToString() part as suggested by Damian should fix that. Is this homework?

Comment: One last question  how in the code can I edit it so that it doesn't show what is being added, rather the next number in the sequence is shown? thanks 
              for example 1    10 +30
                          2    40

Comment: i basically want the + symbols not to be shown in the .csv file